# Creating a CSS Gradient Interface in an In-house CMS

Tags: css, content-management-system, gradient

I have been tasked with creating a CSS gradient interface for my company's in-house CMS. Currently our website builders are using [this website](https://cssgradient.io/) to create a gradient, and then they copy & paste the CSS output into an input field. They would like to bypass the need of going to an external website and copy & pasting by having a comparable in-house CSS gradient interface which would output the CSS directly into the desired input.

I'm sure something like this wouldn't be a quick or easy task, so I'm wondering if there is some kind of third party plugin which would make this project easier? If there was a way to duplicate [this website](https://cssgradient.io/) exactly in my company's CMS, that would be perfect, but I'm assuming there is no easy way to go about doing so. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: I assume you've looked at that site's code to see how they do it? But even when you have that, where is the code going so that people can use it in the more automatic way you describe? e.g. are you adding it to some code editor?

Comment: Yeah, I've dug into that site's code, although it seems fairly complicated to simply reverse engineer it quickly. Some kind of plugin would definitely be easier. The code would be outputting to an input field or just automatically adding the background CSS on the front end.